# Show API results horizontal instead of vertical with HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor

I am building a WordPress web site focused on sports and I am using a sports API to get the latest 10-15 highlights videos from different leagues (basketball, soccer, etc). I have been able to get that information, the problem comes that data is displayed vertically, while I would like it to be shown horizontally with a slider/carousel if possible.

I have been looking at Elementor (it's the builder page I am using for WordPress) and several tutorials but I haven't been able to find anything helpful.

I have the following code:

```
<center>
 [jsoncontentimporter url=API I AM USING]

  {subloop:results:-1}
    {subloop-array:results:-1}

    <a href="{results.strVideo}" target="_blank"><img src="{results.strThumb}" style="width:275px;height:125px;"></a>
    <br>
    <strong style="font-size: 10px;">{results.strHomeTeam}</strong>
    <strong style="font-size: 10px;">{results.intHomeScore}</strong>
    -
    <strong style="font-size: 10px;">{results.intAwayScore}</strong> 
    <strong style="font-size: 10px;">{results.strAwayTeam}</strong>
    <strong style="color:#C3414D;font-size: 14px;">{results.dateEventLocal}</strong>
    <br>
    {/subloop-array:results}
  {/subloop:results}
 [/jsoncontentimporter]

</center>
```

I am using the free version of Elementor but I wouldn't mind too pay for the PRO version if necessary, though I believe there is not any block I could use there, and also would like to know if it's possible to do it with HTML since I would like to get deeper knowledge at it.

Does anyone have any idea or any guide I could check to be able to do this with HTML?

Comment: I think there's a good chance you could achieve what you're looking for simply with some CSS. Are you able to post some HTML that shows the output from your API in the web page? I want to see the structure of the markup and its classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer David, I appreciate it very much

Do you mean the source code? It has more than 650 lines but I could attach you the "main class" part (although it tells me the characters are to long) and the website is not released yet, it's a draft, so I can provide a link yet...

I have no any knowledge about CSS (even less than HTML) but I plan to do some courses next year so if this is a lot of job please don't bother. I really thought I could sort it out with HTML

Comment: Yes, the source code Alberto. Include what you can, or even a screenshot of the source code. I want to see the HTML that the API gives you

Comment: Thank you David, I have created a new page draft called Test where the only it's in it is one API call which is vertical and I would like to get horizontal. I believe the info you need is on line 453.

Here is the Link since I don't see the option to send screenshots on here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VTxQXUTVrHJf6p5xSFWQJ6JmhM6Z6fo_/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for all your time again, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you could do using mostly CSS
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/jOGGPKq

I think what you want to try and do is see if you can add extra HTML around your JSON code. For example, see if you can make some of the text italic with something like

```
<emphasis>{subloop-array:results:-1}</emphasis>
```

If you're able to do this, then the next step would be to add additional divs that wrap all of the results, each individual result, and then details within each result. As shown in this screenshot

[image: additional classes around JSON results]

If you can get to this point then I think you have the problem solved.

You now have some classes that you can target with CSS styling, a basic CSS example would be:

```
.results-wrap {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.result {
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.details {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/jOGGPKq

Comment: Thank you very much for this David. I really appreciate it. My knowledge at CSS is minimal but I will definitely take a deep look at this. Thank you very much for all your work and all your code and I wish you Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, holiday greetings to you as well! And don't worry if CSS isn't your strength, we'll be able to help you. Start by wrapping some JSON tags in <emphasis> ...</emphasis> and see if this changes the output.